# A first-order non-linear ordinary differential equation containing $(f')^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem:**

Find all differentiable functions $f: \text{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies:

$$f(x)\left [ 1-f'(x)^2 \right ] = 2xf'(x) \; \forall x \in \text{D}$$
, whereas $\text{D}$ is a/an (left/right/$\varnothing$)-open interval.

$\;$

This is not an assignment. And, thanks in advance!

Comment: Because of the term into brackets, I should look at something like f(x) = a Sqrt[b - x]

Comment: The problem reduces to solve: f''(x)f(x) + (f'(x))^2 = 0 on D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g:x\mapsto f(x)^2+x^2$, then $2f(x)f'(x)=g'(x)-2x$ hence, multiplying the differential equation by $4f(x)$, one gets
$$
4f(x)^2-(2f(x)f'(x))^2=4x(2f(x)f'(x)),
$$
that is,
$$
4g(x)-4x^2-(g'(x)-2x)^2-4x(g'(x)-2x)=0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
g'(x)^2=4g(x).
$$
Thus, $g'(x)=\pm2\sqrt{g(x)}$, that is, $(\sqrt{g(x)})'=\pm1$, hence $\sqrt{g(x)}=\sqrt{g(0)}\pm x$, that is, 
$$
g(x)=(c+x)^2,
$$ 
for some real number $c$ (the choice $+$ in $\pm$ leads to $c\geqslant0$ and the other choice to $c\leqslant0$). Coming back to $f$, one gets
$$
f(x)=\pm\sqrt{c^2+2cx}.
$$
If $c\gt0$, the maximal interval of definition of $f$ is $(-c/2,+\infty)$, if $c\lt0$, it is $(-\infty,-c/2)$ (note that in both cases this interval contains $0$). If $c=0$, the solution is $f=0$, defined on the whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f^2$

$y'=2ff'$

$f\cdot(1-f' ^2)=2xf'$

$(4f^2-4f^2f'^2)=8xff'$

$4y-y'^2=4xy'$

$y'^2+4xy'=4y$

$y=ax+4b$

$a^2+4ax=4ax+4b$

$a^2=4b$

$y=ax+(a^2/4)$

$f(x)=\pm\sqrt{ax+(a^2/4)}$

$a=\text{constant}$

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how to deduce line 7 from line 6.

Comment: @Did : Sorry for the typing mistake. It isn't y=ax+4b, but it is y=ax+b. That is a conjectural form for the solution. Then, pluging it into the equation prove that the conjecture is true in case of relationship a²=4b

Comment: OK. But there could be hosts of other solutions.

Comment: @Did : OK. That was a short-cut. y'²+4xy'=4y is a Clairaut's EDO. For the method of solving, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClairautsDifferentialEquation.html. This leads to the result already given and nothing more.